# Were feasting caterpillars used to make very light veils, as reported by Charles Babbage?

Tags: technology, clothing

In "On the Economy of Machinery and Manufactures" Charles Babbage gives a very detailed account  of the production of extremely light veil by caterpillars. These fabrics appear 20 times lighter than those made of ordinary silk.

Did (and does) this technology truly exist?

From [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/4238/4238.txt):

> A most extraordinary species
>   of manufacture, which is in a slight degree connected with
>   copying, has been contrived by an officer of engineers residing
>   at Munich. It consists of lace, and veils, with open patterns in
>   them, made entirely by caterpillars. The following is the mode of
>   proceeding adopted: he makes a paste of the leaves of the plant,
>   which is the usual food of the species of caterpillar(4*) he
>   employs, and spreads it thinly over a stone, or other flat
>   substance. He then, with a camel-hair pencil dipped in olive oil,
>   draws upon the coating of paste the pattern he wishes the insects
>   to leave open. This stone is then placed in an inclined position,
>   and a number of the caterpillars are placed at the bottom. A
>   peculiar species is chosen, which spins a strong web; and the
>   animals commencing at the bottom, eat and spin their way up to
>   the top, carefully avoiding every part touched by the oil, but
>   devouring all the rest of the paste. The extreme lightness of
>   these veils, combined with some strength, is truly surprising.
>   One of them, measuring twenty-six and a half inches by seventeen
>   inches, weighed only 1.51 grains; a degree of lightness which
>   will appear more strongly by contrast with other fabrics. One
>   square yard of the substance of which these veils are made weighs
>   4 1/3 grains, whilst one square yard of silk gauze weighs 137
>   grains, and one square yard of the finest patent net weighs 262
>   1/2 grains. The ladies' coloured muslin dresses, mentioned in the
>   table subjoined, cost ten shillings per dress, and each weigh six
>   ounces; the cotton from which they are made weighing nearly six
>   and two-ninth ounces avoirdupois weight.

Comment: The department of textiles of the historic museum of the city of Munich was very kind, and replied to an email of mine: Unfortunately they would not have any account of such a technology having existed in Munich.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [History and Science of Knots](https://books.google.com/books?id=ovDsCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA374&dq=%22sturdy%20mesh.%20This%20method%20of%20manufacture%20proved%20%22%20control&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4v6zuy-LPAhUCEz4KHfRmBE8Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22sturdy%20mesh.%20This%20method%20of%20manufacture%20proved%20%22%20control&f=false)

> It was also in Switzerland that the caterpillar lace experiments were carried out: a design was painted on a varnished wooden board using a 'paint' of succulent leaves pounded into a paste. The board was then propped up against a wall and caterpillars placed along the base; as they climbed up the board eating the paste, they left trails of cocoon-silk which interlaced to form a sturdy mesh. This method of manufacture proved unsuccessful commercially for there were problems of quality control.

Comment: Thank you. While not Munich, Switzerland and their protocol appear quite close.